# Copy to clipboard from hidden input - ngx-clipboard

Tags: angular, clipboard

I want to use ngxClipboard to copy a value from an angular databinding variable. But I can't get it to work for hidden inputs.

```
<input #xpathInput value="{{column.xPath}}" />
<button class="btn" type="button" ngxClipboard="xpathInput">
    <img src="~/src/assets/common/images/clipboardCopy.png" height="40" width="35" alt="Copy to clipboard" >
</button>
```

The above works just fine but when I add `type="hidden"` to the input tag it stops working.

I am not a web dev so I need you're help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this without the `input` by using `[cbContent]`:

```
<button class="btn" type="button" [cbContent]="column.xPath" ngxClipboard>
    <img src="~/src/assets/common/images/clipboardCopy.png" height="40" width="35" alt="Copy to clipboard" >
</button>
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/BPx8jlhiI7fPiHh6XOi3?p=preview)